# return null document.getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbytagname

ihave simple ul element in my webpage like this :

```
<div id="JQueryFTD_Demo" class="demo"><ul class="jqueryFileTree" style="">
    <li class="directory collapsed"><a href="#" rel="/SampleFolder/A/">A</a></li>
    <li class="directory collapsed"><a href="#" rel="/SampleFolder/B/">B</a></li>
    <li class="directory collapsed"><a href="#" rel="/SampleFolder/C/">C</a></li>
    <li class="directory collapsed"><a href="#" rel="/SampleFolder/D/">D</a></li>
    <li class="file ext_accdb"><a href="#" rel="/SampleFolder/SampleDBFile.accdb">SampleDBFile.accdb</a></li>
    <li class="file ext_txt"><a href="#" rel="/SampleFolder/SomeText.txt">SomeText.txt</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

and i try to find  tags in it by javascript :

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
return x.textContent;
```

my return value always is a null, 
would you please help me?

thanks.

Comment: There are 6 `<a>` tags in your document. Which one's content do you expect it to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is pretty simple ... [getElementsByTagname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a collection that is array like.

You have to iterate the collection to interact with properties of each element instance

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is because getElementsByTagName returns a nodelist and you cannot return a value you with out a function

you would have to loop through the nodelist to get the the contents of each

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    console.log(x[i].textContent);
}
```